# How do I mix in ajc with my already setup groovyc/javac ant configuration?

Tags: groovy, aspectj

I recently configured groovy 1.6 (w/Java 6) into my ant build.xml script, so that it compiles everything through groovy, with the embedded javac command:

```
<target name="build-project" depends="init">
    <groovyc destdir="antbin" classpathref="CIMS.classpath">
        <src path="src"/>
        <src path="test"/>
        <classpath refid="CIMS.classpath"/>
        <javac debug="true" debuglevel="${debuglevel}" source="1.6" target="1.6"/>
    </groovyc>
</target>
```

Now I am trying to switch from load-time-weaving of AspectJ 1.6 to compile time. Everything works inside Eclipse, and my test suite has passed (and I also switched from @AspectJ to full blown aspectj). What do I need to add/replace in order to use iajc?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using iajc instead of javac embedded in groovyc target?